# Execution time overhead at index 2^21

Tags: c++, c++17, std, stdvector

#### What do I want to do?

I have written a program which reads data from binary files and does calculation based on the read values. Execution time is most import for this program. To validate that my program is operating within the specified time limits, I tried to **log** all the calculations by storing them inside a `std::vector<std::string>`. And after the time critical execution is done, I write this vector to a file.

#### What is stored inside the vector?

In the vector I write the execution time (`std::chrono:steady_clock.now()`) and the current clock time (`std::chrono::system_clock::now()` with date.h by Howard Hinnant).

#### What did I observe?

While analyzing the results I stumble over the following pattern. Independent on the input data the mean execution time of 0.003ms for one operation explodes to ~20ms for a single operation at one specific reproducible index. After this, the execution time of all operations goes back to 0.003ms. The index of the execution time explosion is every time **2097151**. Since **2^21** equals 2097152, something happens at 2^21 that slows down the entire program. The same effect can be observed with 2^22 and 2^23. Even more interesting is that the lag is doubled (2^21 = ~20ms, 2^22 = ~43ms, 2^23 =~81ms ). I googled about this specific number and the only thing I found was some [node.js stuff](https://newbedev.com/how-much-is-the-limit-of-promise-all) which uses c++ under the hood.

#### What do I suspect?

At index 2^21 a memory area must be expanded, and that is why the delay occurs.

#### Questions

1. Is my assumption correct and the size of the vector is the problem?
2. How can I debug such a Phenomenon? (To be certain, that purely the vector is the problem)
3. Can I allocate enough memory beforehand to avoid the memory expansion?
4. What could I use instead of a `std::vector`, which supports > 10.000.000.000 elements?

Comment: I doubt that 2^21 is the first time where the `std::vector` does re-allocate. Maybe, you just didn't notice the extra effort as long as it's still smaller. Anyway, to overcome this, you could simply use `std::vector::reserve()` to prevent any re-allocation. (You have to know the final size from the beginning, of course, or just make a max. estimation.)

Comment: Either use `reserve` if you know how many elements you will need, or you could try using a different container, `std::deque` for example has a constant complexity of `push_back` compared to `std::vector` amortized constant.

Comment: I think your std::vector reallocates at those specific points (doubling reserved size each time). That means that at each doubling memory needs to be copied resulting in hickups. (it probably gets a lot worse when your physical memory starts to run out too). But yes you could try pre-allocating enough memory in the vector.

Comment: Making your vector hold the times directly rather than the strings and then formatting to string during file writing is likely to reduce the magnitude of the slow down

Comment: @scheffs-cat, @p-kramer I will start a test where I reserve the maximum size of the vector. @alan-birtles Furthermore I will try what happens if I save directly the `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` object instead of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by reserving memory by using `std::vector::reserve()` before the time critical part of my program. Thanks to all the comments.

Here the working code I used:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> myLogVector;
myLogVector.reserve(12000000);
//...do time critical stuff, without reallocating storage
```